# Cronjobs Permission denied

Tags: cron, scrapy, linode

I set cron job on the Linode server.
my run.sh file in the root directory.

```
echo $(../uploads + /usr/bin/date +"%Y-%m-%d_%H%M")_name.csv
```

when I run sh run.sh
my scrapy folder is in **root/my_project** and upload data into **root/uploads**
i debugging error using eco
getting error

```
/root/uploads: Permission denied
_Mobile_Nshopping.csv
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have to use
**echo ../uploads/$(/usr/bin/date +"%Y-%m-%d_%H%M")_name.csv instead of under bracket.**